# Spinner is not working properly

Tags: java, android, if-statement, spinner

The problem I am having is that I want `spinner2` to populate after I select (for example) Canada, but for some reason `spinner2` gets populated at startup instead of after I select Canada. I also connected a string array to `spinner2` to make sure that it would startup with nothing but it still doesn't work. Here is what I have so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        addListenerOnButton();
        addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
        R.array.countries, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                TextView tv = (TextView)v;   // cast the View to a TextView
                if ("Canada".equals(tv.getText().toString()));
                {
                    addItemsOnSpinner2();
                }
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });
    }     


    // add items into spinner dynamically

    public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {     

        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("hello");
        list.add("holla");
        list.add("hey");
        list.add("hi");
        ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }     



    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {     
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);     
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);     
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner2());     
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner2());     


    }     

    public void addListenerOnButton() {     

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Result : " + 
                    "\nSpinner 1 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) +
                    "\nSpinner 2 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
    }     
}
```

**Spinner2.java***

```
public class Spinner2 implements OnItemSelectedListener {     

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
            parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the deal.. the `onItemSelected` method is still called when the Spinner has just been created without you selecting any option. A simple workaround for this is to add an extra option in spinner liek "Select" or "None" and have a `if-else` construct in `onItemSelected` method just like this:-

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    if(pos==0) {
        //do something;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
            parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @d3m0li5h3r rightly mentions

> onItemSelected method is still called when the Spinner has just been initialised

So, here is a workaround, instead of adding extra element in spinner,..

```
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    boolean check = false;

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                 if(count){
                    TextView tv = (TextView)v;   // cast the View to a TextView
                    if ("Canada".equals(tv.getText().toString()));
                    {
                        addItemsOnSpinner2();
                    }
                }
                  check = true;
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: i got it to work by replacing "count" with "pos==0". 
0 = first item inside the spinner